# Recoding multiple columns in a R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a medical data frame in R, which currently holds 700 columns. It also includes information about medication given to patients. This information is spread on hundreds of columns (for each class).
The problem is, that the information is stored as free-text. I want to change the information to 1 and 0, where 1 code that there is text in the cell and 0 represents NA, like so:

```
dat$Admission_Ace.Inhibitors..Plain <- factor(ifelse(is.na(dat$Admission_Ace.Inhibitors..Plain), 0, 1))
```

However, despite this solution working great, it only works for one column at a time, and I need to recode hundreds. 
So far, I have been unsuccessful in automating the prosses. Can you please assist me?

Note: I have a vector containing all of the colum names that need this change, that I got using this method:

```
admission <- names(dat)[grepl("Admission", names(dat), ignore.case = T )]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R, using `lapply` :

```
dat[admission] <- lapply(dat[admission], function(x) +(!is.na(x)))
```

In `dplyr` using `mutate_at` :

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% mutate_at(vars(admission), ~+(!is.na(.)))
```

`is.na` checks for `NA` values, `!` negates them and `+` converts the `TRUE`/`FALSE` values to `1`/`0` respectively.

Using reproducible example,

```
dat <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, NA), b  =c(NA, NA, 3, 2))
dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) +(!is.na(x)))
dat

#  a b
#1 1 0
#2 1 0
#3 1 1
#4 0 1
```

Comment: When I run your code, it gave this weird output and didn't change the columns themselfs:  
Admission_Vitamin.D.And.Analogues Admission_Vitamin.K.Antagonists Release_Ace.Inhibitors.And.Diuretics
1                                 0                               0                                 <NA>
  Release_Ace.Inhibitors..Plain Release_Adrenergics.And.Other.Drugs.For.Obstructive.Airway.Diseases
1                          <NA>                                                           <NA>
as you can see, it also includes columns that were'nt in the list. (it goes like this to all columns)

Comment: @Epic_Yarin_God `lapply` code should change `dat` itself but for `dplyr` code you need to assign the value to an object `dat <- dat %>% mutate_at(vars(admission), ~+(!is.na(.)))` There was a typo in the `lapply` code, I have corrected it now.